# Access input field of parent page from within .js in an iframe on same domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, var

I have a .js file that runs on a page and interacts with the data already there.  That .js file creates an iframe which loads another page that also has a .js file installed (both with GreaseMonkey).  I'm trying to make the .js file running in the iframe grab a var from the parent page.  Both are on the same domain, but it will not access the data.  Here's what I have:

js1:

```
var myvar1 = document.getElementsByName('nameofinputfromparentpage')[0].value;
```

js2:

```
var myvar2 = parent.document.getElementsByID('page1').getElementsByName('nameofinputfromparentpage')[0].value;
```

or

```
var myvar2 = myvar1 (or parent.myvar1 or window.myvar1 or a dozen other variances...)
```

I've tried pushing the var from js1 to js2 with something like: 
`window.frames[iframeName].variableName` or using `contentDocument`/`contentWindow`.
I just can't seem to get the syntax right to make it actually pull the data...

So... the page source of the parent page has an input box, how do I get that info to be accessed in .js running in an iframe of another .js on the parent page?  Thank you everyone for your help!  :)

Comment: did you get your answer? See my last comment. Don't combine get by name and get by ID, just use one at a time!

Answer (score 0):

From inside the IFrame the parent property refers to the parent, so:

```
parent.document.getElementByID('myInputBox').value;
```

will access the contents of an element with the ID 'myInputBox' located in the parent of this document. In the case that the script is executed from a top level document outside a frame object, the property parent=self. Please note that the ID property must be unique within a single HTML document, so the function is getElementByID() not getElementsByID(). Also there is no need for an index because there will only be one element returned.

Comment: I apologize, I do have it as getElementByID in my code; I just had a typo in my question.  The problem is the content I'm working with doesn't all have IDs; most of it was written with just names (not by me!)--hence having to use the getElementsByName for everything...  Does it HAVE to be with ID only?


As far as the code, that's what I have (plus the getname addon), but it doesn't pull the info at all.  Even having an alert with it, stops the rest of the script from loading:
alert (parent.document.getElementsByName('name')[0].value);

Can it be a problem with running a .js from within a .js?

Comment: No, the parent property of your frame is the one you want. Maybe a problem with Internet explorer (bane of my existence). How about accessing by tag name? I just like ID because they are unique. Names and tags are returned as arrays, so use the index.

Comment: I just realized, you are using the name and the ID both! Just use one. No add on. That's your problem!